# If partial derivatives w.r.t. x and y are equal at each point (x,y) then which options are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-derivative

> Let, $f$ be a function on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$. Then which is(/are) correct?
>
> 1. $f(x,y)-f(y,x)=(x-y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^*,y^*)+(y-x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x^*,y^*)$.
> 2. $f$ is constant on all lines parallel to the line $x=-y$.
> 3. $f(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$.
> 4. $f(x,y)=f(-y,x)$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$.

First we consider an example $f(x,y)=(x+y+5)^2$.

Then the condition $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ is satisfied.

So, clearly **option 3** is **FALSE**.

Now , $f(-y,x)=(x-y+5)^2\not=f(x,y)$. So , **option 4** is also **FALSE**.

Now equation of lines parallel to the line $x=-y$ is $x+y=c.$ Then , on this $f(x,y)=(5+c)^2=constant$ . So **option 2** may be true.

> I want to prove **option 1 and option 2** , if they are correct. How I  can do it  ?

Comment: Your example function doesn't satisfy the hypothesis. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = 2xy + y^2 - x^2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = x^2 + 2xy - y^2$.

Comment: Ohh.....That's my mistake..

Comment: @  Daniel Fischer) Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

For option 2, note any such line can be parameterized as $l(t) = (a+t,b-t),-\infty< t < \infty,$ where $a,b$ are real constants. Consider $f(l(t)).$